# Send email from rails app in heroku environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, actionmailer

I have deployed my rails web app to heroku. Now I want send email to the user who signed up to my web app. I want to send email from my business email. Let say my business email is `abc@business-email.in`.

I am getting error when I checked by doing `heroku logs`.

> 86ms: SocketError (getaddrinfo: Name or service not known):

Here is my mails settings in `config/production.rb`

```
#Heroku mail configuration
config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
ActionMailer::Base.delivery_method = :smtp
ActionMailer::Base.perform_deliveries = true
ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
:address   => "smtp.business-email.in",
:domain => 'myApp.herokuapp.com',
:port      => 25,
:user_name => "abc@business-email.in",
:password  => ENV['SMTP_PASSWORD'], 
:authentication => :plain,
:enable_starttls_auto => true
}
```

Comment: what you have set in `config.action_mailer.default_url_options`?

Comment: I have not set it? @RaviMariya

Comment: try setting your Heroku app URL into it

Comment: Do I have to set it in inside `production.rb` @RaviMariya

Comment: yes, just check setting it like `ActionMailer::Base.default_url_options[:host] = 'your heroku app url'`, might solve the problem, also if you can include how are you sending mail, a sample code, it will help others to solve the problem